# Saving a Range of data as a PDF with a button in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that will bring up a save dialog box when a button in my excel sheet is clicked:

```
Sub SavePDF()
Dim X
X = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=Range("F8") & "_" & Range("F6"), _
     FileFilter:="PDF files, *.pdf", _
     Title:="Save PDF File")
If TypeName(X) = "Boolean" Then
Else
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=X, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End If
End Sub
```

...what I need is to add something to this that will only save a certain range of data when the button is clicked. My range is: B2 to J44. At the moment when I click the save button is it saving the whole sheet which I do not want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code sample doesn't seem to save anything, but `ExportAsFixedFormat ` method of `Range` object should help you.

Comment: @user3964075 - Hi, I have realized this and I have edited the question with the new code :)

Comment: Replace `ActiveSheet` with `ActiveSheet.Range("B2:J44")`

Comment: Legendary, thank you @user3964075 this now works... I still have a problem where this code will not save the file if the file name already exists in the folder I am trying to save it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreatePDF()
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim sFile As String

    Set wSheet = ActiveSheet
    sFile = Replace(Replace(wSheet.Name, " ", ""), ".", "_") _
            & "_" _
            & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd\_hhmm") _
            & ".pdf"
    sFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFile

    vFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=sFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

    If vFile <> "False" Then
    wSheet.Range("B2:J44").ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        FileName:=vFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

    MsgBox "PDF file has been created."
    End If
End Sub
```

See Examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee834871%28office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

---

File is save as **`SheetName_TodaysDate_HoursMinutes`**

if you would like to add seconds just add **`ss`** next to **`_hhmmss`**

Comment: Thank you, this has fixed another problem I had too, this works perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help

Comment: Just one thing with this code is that if you go to save a file that has the same file name it does not ask you if you're sure you want to overwrite the file, it just overwrites it without warning?

Comment: if the name exist the code just overwrites without asking - the PDF will be saved as `sheetName_TodaysDate_hourminutes` if you need you could add seconds `hhmmss`